# Rstudio server not starting in browser

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, rstudio

I connected a GCP VM to my local machine and installed RStudio per this tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/r-studio-server-on-google-cloud-dd69b8bff80b

However, when I try to access RStudio server on chrome using http://external-ip:8787 I get a "took too long to respond error.

1. My installation was successful.
2. I checked the firewall settings on GCP and it's configured correctly to port 8787.
3. This is the current status:

```
● rstudio-server.service - RStudio Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rstudio-server.service; enabled; vendor p
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-07-06 21:56:00 UTC; 31min ago
  Process: 8290 ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall -TERM rserver (code=exited, status=0/S
  Process: 8446 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver (code=exited, stat
 Main PID: 8447 (rserver)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rstudio-server.service
           └─8447 /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver

Jul 06 21:56:00 datascience-2 systemd[1]: Starting RStudio Server...
Jul 06 21:56:00 datascience-2 systemd[1]: Started RStudio Server.
```

Could someone please help me resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried checking the firewall inside the VM instance, allowing the port 8787?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I had a port 8787 on GCP but not on that particular instance! Adding it to the instance resolved the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, checking the firewall within the instance and allowing the port 8787 will fix the issue, for future readers, here's how to do it in Ubuntu:

> sudo ufw allow 8787